# Cross Product in Euclidean Space with infinite Dimensions

Tags: vector-spaces

How can the cross product of two vectors with infinite tuples be found? ie
If $ A = (a_1, a_2, a_3,.....) $

and $ B = (b_1, b_2, b_3,....) $

Comment: The usual [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) is only defined in $3$-dimensions.  Perhaps you mean a  cartesian product, or a tensor product?

Answer (score 1):

By definition the cross product of two vectors is a vector that is perpendicular to the two vectors and has length equal to the area of the parallelogram spanned by the vectors (plus orientation). If the dimension is $<3$ such a vector exists iff the given vectors are parallel. In the 3-space  it exists always and is unique. If the dimension is $>3$ it exists but is not unique. In an infinite dim space before defining a cross-product you need to define the length of a vector and the area of a parallelogram.

Comment: What if I have the lengths but I miss the angles? How could I specify the nature of the parallelogram?

Comment: To define both you need dot products. The the area is the absolute value of dot product and the length is the square root of the dot square.